# How can I remove PDF download button?

Tags: 8, javascript

I am using the pdf_reader module and showing my PDF on the node. Now, I am supposed to hide the download button. For this purpose, I wrote the below javascript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  document.querySelector('#download').style.display = 'none';
});
```

It's also in my theme's libraries.yml file. The last thing I did was write a hook_preprocess_node implementation and put in the below code:

```
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node->getType() == 'e_dergi') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'conference_lite/custom';
  }
```

But I can't hide the download button for the life of me. What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

If your theme name is fluffiness in "fluffiness.info.yml" add following lines

```
libraries:
  - fluffiness/global-scripts
```

in your file "fluffiness.libraries.yml" add following lines

```
global-scripts:
  version: 1.x
js: 
  js/fluffiness.js: {} 

dependencies:
  - core/jquery
  - core/drupal
```

in your file "js/fluffiness.js" add following code

```
(function (Drupal, drupalSettings, once) {
   Drupal.behaviors.hideElement = {
     attach: function (context, settings) {
      jQuery("#download").hide();
     }
   }
 } (Drupal, drupalSettings, once));
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work :(

Comment: Please check 
1) file added on page using "View Page Source" 2) check any js error in browser

Comment: Page source doesn't include it, however an additional console.log says it's loaded.

Comment: i think you should go through in detail, the way of adding js as mentioned here https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme look at this regarding cuddly-slider.js as they have explained in detail this might help you.

Comment: @Kartagis Any JS errors in browser's console? Why not do it via CSS `#download { display: none; }`

Comment: @NoSssweat no JS errors in the console. Trying with CSS absolutely doesn't work :(

Comment: @Kartagis is the custom CSS file being loaded? You can check with: Right mouse click >> inspect element >> network >> CSS and reload page. If it is, then try `#download { display: none !important; }`